# Does taking dramamine prevent your body from adapting to motion sickness

Tags: motion-sickness

I am asking this question specifically about VR motion sickness but in all my research I have found that it is very similar to any other motion sickness.

It appears that with VR motion sickness people get used to it after some time.  This function similar to any immersion therapy for motion sickness.
People have also reported dramamine being effective at controlling symptoms.

I am wondering if taking dramamine and using VR counts towards adaptation time?  I am specifically looking for any research that shows if treating motion sickness with drugs prevents adaptation

I would also be interested to know if any premises that I have stated based on casual research contradict science.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Since you already have some research on the topic, could you [edit] your question to share it? It would give those trying to answer your question a good starting point. Thanks!

Comment: My research mostly comes from users describing their personal experiences with VR, and not something I would consider evidence